# Correct usage of "so.....as"

Tags: conjunctions

I would to know if there is any error in the below sentence.

> No other man was so successful an administrator as James was.

As far as I am concerned so...as is used in negative sense. Here I am in doubt if the above sentence is having a negative or a positive sense.

Comment: "No" at the very beginning gives a negative sense.

Comment: A better expression would be ‘no other man had been as successful an administrator as James was’ or ‘no other man has been as successful an administrator as James (is)’. The use of past perfect in the first sentence shows that up till a certain point in time in the past when James became a successful administrator, no one else had reached that level. The use of present perfect in the second sentence shows that up till now (present), no one had been as successful as James.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments!!! It seems from your comments that the above sentence is correct but it can be improved using "as... as" as mentioned by danielloid.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "No other man was so successful an administrator as James was"

> I would to know if there is any error in the below sentence.

No.

> I am in doubt if the above sentence is having a negative or a positive sense.

By the fact that it begins with the word "No", it has a type of negative sense, but there is also a positive sense: "James was successful".

Next, there are questions in the comments about two further topics:

1. If "as...as" is better than "so...as"

"so...as" has a literary, poetic or archaic quality. It has a nice ring to it. If you are writing a novel then it could be a good choice.  Grammar texts indicate that "so...as" should only be used in phrases with a negative sense, while "as... as" may be used in either case (positive or negative).

"as...as" is straight-forward, clear, and correct. It's more standard, and commonly heard in US English.

2. If past perfect or present perfect are preferable tenses.

This is a separate question, and not connected to "so...as".
Each verb tense has it's own meaning. "is", "was", "had been", "has been", etc. They are all valid tenses with different meanings. Each of those tenses could conceivably be applied to the sentence. The simple past "was" isn't wrong, per se.